# Implementing Unit Of Work in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have implemented the Repository pattern in my WinForms Application:

UnitOfWork:

```
using RCCGSPP.Core;
using RCCGSPP.Persistence.Repositories;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace RCCGSPP.Persistence
{
    //Implements the Logic for Methods in the IUnitOfWork Interface
    public class UnitOfWork
    {
        //Our App contextClassName
        private readonly SPPContext _context;
        private DbContext dbContext;

        //Recieves our App ContextClassName
        public UnitOfWork(SPPContext context)
        {
            //stores our App ContextName in _context
            _context = context;
            //Then uses the context to initialise both Repositories
            Persons = new PersonRepository(_context);
            SundayServices = new SundayServiceRepository(_context);
            UserPasses = new UserRepository(_context);
            NewComers = new NewComerRepository(_context);
        }

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        //properties 
        public PersonRepository Persons { get; private set; }
        public SundayServiceRepository SundayServices { get; private set; }
        public UserRepository UserPasses { get; private set; }
        public NewComerRepository NewComers { get; private set; }

        //Calls the SaveChanges on the Context
        public int Complete()
        {
            return _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Implementation of the Dispose Method to Dispose the Context
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

My Form whwere I want to use my UnitOfWork, I have declared it as a readonly property so I have included it in the contructor to initialise it but since by form is load from another at the click of a Button I get "`There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'unitOfWork'`"

Form Where To Use UNITOFWORK

```
    public partial class Register : MaterialForm
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        string userName;
        string psswrd;
        string Confirmpsswrd;

        public Register(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Set your preferred colors &theme (Material Skin)
            var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
            materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
            materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
            materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.Blue400, Primary.Red900, Primary.Brown900, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.BLACK);
            //prevent Form from Resizing 
            Sizable = false;

            //UnitOfWork
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }


        private void Register_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the User email and Password to register in the DB
            userName = textEmail.Text;
            psswrd = textPassword.Text;
            Confirmpsswrd = textConfirmPassword.Text;
            //Compare the password
            bool conRes = ComparePassword(psswrd, Confirmpsswrd);
            if (conRes)
            {
                //Insert to db using the UnitOfWork
                UserPass userToDb = new UserPass
                {
                    UserName = this.userName,
                    password = this.psswrd,

                };

                _unitOfWork.UserPasses.Add(userToDb);
                //Commit calling complete()
                _unitOfWork.Complete();
                //FeedBack Registered Sucessfull
                LabelErrorPassword.Text = "Successful, Login!";
            }
            else
            {
                LabelErrorPassword.BackColor = Color.Red;
                LabelErrorPassword.Text = "The Passwords don't match!"; //show in the Label that password are not the same
            }
        }


        /**********Method to compare Password**********************/
        public bool ComparePassword(string pss1, string pss2)
        {
            if (pss1.Equals(pss2))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
```

lOADING MY fORM :

```
private void BtnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //lOAD THE rEGISTER fORM,
    Register nForm = new Register();
    nForm.Show();
}
```

How can I make use of my UnitOfWork in my WinForm Application.

Comment: Winforms really like having a default parameterless constructor, especially if you want to use the form designer: you can fight it, but it's better just to go along with it. You could add a method to set the unit of work after you create the form but before you show it.

Comment: You can use IoC containers to register ad resolve all dependencies read this https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63791/ef6-code-first-unit-of-work-pattern-with-ioc-di

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stuartd said, the parameterless contructor for a Form in WinForms is recommended. But of course you can add a constructor with arguments.

```
public Register()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //Set your preferred colors &theme (Material Skin)
    var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
    materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
    materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
    materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.Blue400, Primary.Red900, Primary.Brown900, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.BLACK);
    //prevent Form from Resizing 
    Sizable = false;

    //UnitOfWork, not initialized here
    //_unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}    

public Register(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : this() // call default constructor!
{
  _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

I strongly recommend to leave all the auto-generated and custom initialization code in the default (parameterless) constructor. So, the WinForms designer does not stop working.

We use this strategy in combination with DI containers in several projects  without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thank You all.

I have used the Simple Ijector package to Inject the UnitOfWork into my Program.cs as Follow:

```
static void Main()
        {

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Bootstrap();
            //Get instance of my Registered HomeForm
            Application.Run((container.GetInstance<Home>()));

        }


        private static void Bootstrap()
        {
            // Create the container as usual.
            container = new Container();

            // Register my types, for instance:
            container.Register<UnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
            //Register my HomeForm
            container.Register<Home>();

            // Optionally verify the container.
            //container.Verify();
        }

    }
```

Then in my Principal Form: I injected the registered UnitOfWork in it's constructor:

```
//Declare my UnitOfwORK
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public Home(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
```

Then I pass it to the New Register Form that will be loaded at the click of the Register Button, inside of which I will use the UnitOfWork to persist  and commit to the DB

```
 //lOAD THE rEGISTER fORM,
        Register nForm = new Register(this._unitOfWork);
            nForm.Show();
        }
```

Finally in the Register I use this UnitOfWork to perform my CRUD Operations and Commit to the DB:

```
public partial class Register : MaterialForm
    {
        //Declare my UnitOfwORK
        private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        string userName;
        string psswrd;
        string Confirmpsswrd;


        //I Inject IUnitOfOfClass with the Help of Simple Injector dependency injection library
        public Register(UnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Set your preferred colors &theme (Material Skin)
            var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
            materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
            materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
            materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.Blue400, Primary.Red900, Primary.Brown900, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.BLACK);
            //prevent Form from Resizing 
            Sizable = false;

            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }

        private void SetUnitOfWork()
        {

        }
        private void Register_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the User email and Password to register in the DB
            userName = textEmail.Text;
            psswrd = textPassword.Text;
            Confirmpsswrd = textConfirmPassword.Text;
            //Compare the password
            bool conRes = ComparePassword(psswrd, Confirmpsswrd);
            if (conRes)
            {
                //Insert to db using the UnitOfWork
                UserPass userToDb = new UserPass
                {
                    UserName = this.userName,
                    password = this.psswrd,
                    LastAcess = DateTime.Now

                };

               _unitOfWork.UserPasses.Add(userToDb);
                //Commit calling complete()
               _unitOfWork.Complete();
                //FeedBack Registered Sucessfull
                LabelErrorPassword.Text = "Successful, Login!";
            }
            else
            {
                LabelErrorPassword.BackColor = Color.Red;
                LabelErrorPassword.Text = "The Passwords don't match!"; //show in the Label that password are not the same
            }
        }


        /**********Method to compare Password**********************/
        public bool ComparePassword(string pss1, string pss2)
        {
            if (pss1.Equals(pss2))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else return false;
        }
    }
```

It might not be the best way to implement it but It works absolutely fine, I have tested it and I could see the data in the database.